# How to return user messages sorted by date ASC

Tags: php, gmail-api

Currently, I'm using the Google composer package (google/apiclient) to create and access client's mailboxes over the gmail api.

Filters work fine but I can't seem to set the order of the returned messages. Currently, I have to download all messages then parse to SimpleObject and sort then - which is not not very effective.

My question is thus, is there any way to sort by/order by the list of messages being returned by the api? (Order by message received date in my case)

EDIT:
Seems it is ordering by default as descending.

```
[class.app.php](INFO) - InternalDate : 1465905719000 / 2016-06-14 12:01:59

[class.app.php](INFO) - InternalDate : 1465905637000 / 2016-06-14 12:00:37

[class.app.php](INFO) - InternalDate : 1465902012000 / 2016-06-14 11:00:12

[class.app.php](INFO) - InternalDate : 1465894821000 / 2016-06-14 09:00:21

[class.app.php](INFO) - InternalDate : 1465894809000 / 2016-06-14 09:00:09

[class.app.php](INFO) - InternalDate : 1465893175000 / 2016-06-14 08:32:55

[class.app.php](INFO) - InternalDate : 1465885043000 / 2016-06-14 06:17:23

[class.app.php](INFO) - InternalDate : 1465882050000 / 2016-06-14 05:27:30

[class.app.php](INFO) - InternalDate : 1465875177000 / 2016-06-14 03:32:57

[class.app.php](INFO) - InternalDate : 1465862969000 / 2016-06-14 00:09:29
```

For my purposes though, how to change this to be ascending instead?

Comment: I think the messages are already sorted by descending date by default. You can check the `internalDate`-field on the messages to verify this.

Comment: Thanks @Tholle, see my edit.

Comment: I don't think you can get messages in ascending order.

Comment: Interesting, as that is something that the latest o365 v2 API offers. Currently I'm stuck on ordering it after fetch then I guess.

EDIT: Come on google! :)

Comment: This is still (March, 2019) not possible. Strange.